# Can't locate Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm in @INC though it's seems to be installed

Tags: linux, perl, cpan, cpanm

```
Can't locate Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .)
```

though it's installed:

```
% perl -e'use CPAN; install "Spreadsheet:WriteExcel"'

Going to read '/home/aspect_mkn8rd/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sun, 27 Apr 2014 09:41:02 GMT
Spreadsheet::WriteExcel is up to date (2.40).
```

That's where it located, yep?

```
% ls -la /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/auto/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel

total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 апр.  28 13:11 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 root root 4096 апр.  28 13:11 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 2519 апр.  28 13:11 .packlist


% cat /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/auto/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/.packlist 

/usr/local/bin/chartex
/usr/local/man/man1/chartex.1p
/usr/local/man/man3/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel.3pm
/usr/local/man/man3/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::BIFFwriter.3pm
<..>
/usr/local/man/man3/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Workbook.3pm
/usr/local/man/man3/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Worksheet.3pm
/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm
/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/BIFFwriter.pm
/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/Big.pm
<..>
/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/Workbook.pm
/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/Worksheet.pm

% perldoc -l Spreadsheet::WriteExcel   

/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm
```

So why? What should I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet%3a%3aParseExcel) and [`Spreadsheet::WriteExcel`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel) are different modules.

Have you installed the former too?

If not, just do the following:

```
perl -e'use CPAN; install "Spreadsheet::ParseExcel"'
```

Comment: oh. Seems like I need to sleep sometimes.. Will accept when I'll be able to.

Comment: ;)  S'ok, we've all been there.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 ways to go about the same:

1. use `lib '/path/to/directory'` where the module is stored
2. `perl -I /path/to/directory test.pl` where you include the module using the command line option -I

For more information, please refer to
https://perlmaven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations .

*Voilá*, here you go, happy coding